Contradiction in my algebraic topology arguments, where is my misunderstanding?
I am currently studying algebraic topology for an exam and found an argument that obviously can't work, but I don't see why: So take any homotopy equivalence $f: \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2$, then I claim, using my wrong argument, that it must be orientation preserving. Which I don't think is true, cause we could consider the map $A \times \textrm{Id}$ where $A$ is the antipodal map. (which I think isn't orientation preserving)
Now to my argument, we consider the cohomology groups of $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2$, which we obtain via Künneth formula. We can take generators $1 \times \nu$ and $\nu \times 1$ where $\nu$ is the generator of $H^2(S^2)$. Then we should get a generator $\gamma \in H_4(\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2)$ by using the cup pairing: $\gamma := \nu \cup \nu$. Now to the argument: We know that $f$ induces an isomorphism on homology, now we also know $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2$ is orientable, connected and compact, so let $o_M$ be the fundamental class. Then I use naturality of the cup product and deduce: $f^*(\nu \cup \nu)(o_M) = (\nu \cup \nu)(f_*(o_M)) = \textrm{deg}(f) (\nu \cup \nu)(o_M) = \textrm{deg}(f)\gamma (o_M) \neq 0$ but also $f^*(\nu \cup \nu) = (f^*\nu \cup f^*\nu)(o_M) = (-1)^4 \nu (F^2(f_*(o_M))) \nu(R^2(f_*(o_M))) = \textrm{deg}(f)^2 (\nu \cup \nu) (o_M) = \textrm{deg}(f)^2 \gamma(o_M) \neq 0$. (Here F and R denote the front face and rear face maps, used to explicitly express the cup product) From all this we then get $\textrm{deg}(f) = \textrm{deg}(f)^2$ implying that the degree of $f$ is positive and thus f must be orientation preserving.
Thank you in advance! I'm sure there is some sign I forgot or perhaps there is a deeper misunderstanding. In any case it'd be super helpful if someone could resolve the issue here!

The problem is that the formula $(\alpha \smile \beta) (\phi) = \alpha(F(\phi))\beta(R(\phi))$ works only for singular simplices (basis elements). If $\phi$ is a singular chain, you should extend this formula by linearity. That is, if $\phi$ is a singular simplex and $c \in \mathbb Z$, then $(\alpha \smile \beta) (c \phi) = c\alpha(F(\phi))\beta(R(\phi))$. What you did in the second computation is $(\alpha \smile \beta) (c \phi) = \alpha(F(c\phi))\beta(R(c\phi))$, which suggests that the expression $(\alpha \smile \beta) (\phi)$ is non-linear in $\phi$.

Oh yeah you're right! Thank you so much!

@Matsmir: I suggest that you turn this into an answer, not just a comment.
